# Syntastic: How to check .c file with cpp checker

Tags: syntastic, vim-syntastic

I have some files with .c extensions that use features of C++.  Syntastic is checking these files with C checker which is reporting errors.  Can you force synstastic to use C++ checker for .c files?

Comment: There are few ways to achieve that: you can set `filetype` for your C files to `cpp`, or you can use `syntastic_filetype_map`, or you can run `:SyntasticCheck cpp/gcc` etc., or you can add `cpp/gcc` to `syntastic_c_checkers`, or you can add `cpp/gcc` etc. to `b:syntastic_checkers`.  It's all in the manual.

Comment: Thanks.  g:syntastic_c_checkers = ['g++'] seems to work as well as  g:syntastic_filetype_map = { "c": "cc"}.

Comment: Actually, setting `g:syntastic_c_checkers` to `['g++']` has no useful effect (the useless effects may include producing a warning).  `g++` is not a known checker, and `+` is not a valid character in a checker's name.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  That was a typo and should have been ['cpp'].  However, after further inspection :SyntasticInfo is returning curenntly enabled checkers = '-' after setting g:syntastic_c_checkers to ['cpp'].

Comment: _That was a typo and should have been ['cpp']._ - That isn't what I said.  Try it with `['cpp/gcc']`, literally (assuming a decently recent version of syntastic).

Comment: With g:syntastic_c_checkers = ['cpp/gcc'] enabled checkers = cpp/gcc.  However, file is not being checked.

Comment: Then please open an issue at the [issue tracker](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic/issues).  Make sure to explain what did you do, what did you expect to happen, and what happened instead.